# Why does this calc() function not work in transform scale?

Tags: css, css-transforms, css-calc

`calc()` apparently works in a transform, but this does not:

```
transform: scale(calc(0.75 + (0.3 - 0.75) * ((100vw - 320px) / (780 - 320))));
```

Also, this works, but it's basically the same formula, only with a percent vs decimal. Only added this so you can see the formula works here:

```
right: calc(30% + (75 - 30) * ((100vw - 320px) / (780 - 320)));
```

I have a container that has a width as a percent, and max width of 300px, for example. I want a child of it to always scale, using `transform:scale()`, to a percent of the parent's actual current width.

Why does my transform `calc` function not work? Using Chrome.

The `100vw - 320px` is there to calculate between minimum an max size of the window width. Is it possible to do that here?

Comment: scale doesn't take any unit it need only number

Comment: I don't have a unit. Only 0.75.

Comment: and what about the vw and px ? they are unit ... by the way the whole formula is invalid, you cannot add number with unit

Comment: Ok. I need that part of the equation to calculate minimum an max of the window width. How can I do that?

Comment: Updated my question.

Comment: It can be done, but instead of using `(100vw - 300px)` in your formula, you need to use a wrapper and give it that width. Now, any children you place in this wrapper will start from `100%` being the `calc(100vw - 300px)` above. Provide a practical example and I'll show you a practical solution for achieving what you want. Without a [mcve], your question is nor unanswerable neither useful for future users, which is the main criteria for answering questions on [so]. Please read [ask] for details.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu will do when we have time here. Thanks.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu can you elaborate how using a wrapper with your trick will make it working, I am not following .. we are talking about the scale property not the right property

Comment: I updated my question with a use case.

Comment: so it's a XY probleme then, using scale will scale both height and width, so if it was only scaleX then it will be more clear

Comment: why not simply using `width:30%;max-width:320px` ?

Comment: In theory you're right, Temani. It's not possible. Because it would still be units inside `scale()`. But in practice, as long as we know the desired result, most, if not all things, are possible. In the end it's virtual space. @BB, I don't know what you call a "use case" but I was expecting a *runnable* [mcve]. Please provide the markup you currently have and describe what should happen.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu yes if we know the *desired result* as this is clearly an XY problem and a wrong approach to achieve something that would be easy using other techniques.

Comment: @BB, the XY problem Temani refers to is [described here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). It currently appears you think by solving Y you solve X but in reality that's not the case, on the contrary. Please describe what you actually want to achieve, not how you think it can be achieved. I don't mean to sound aggressive or condescending. Both myself and Temani are trying to help but we're currently unable to understand the real challenge/requirement.

Comment: Updated again. Don't know if that's more clear.

Comment: Sorry I realized I made this question confusing. I may have to post another question when I have time...

Comment: Does [this](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/qe47c9b3/) do what you want?

Comment: The border looks to be the right size, but the scaled text appears to stay at a static scale.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two issues. The first one is about the formula without scale:

```
calc(0.75 + (0.3 - 0.75) * ((100vw - 320px) / (780 - 320)))
```

This is invalid because you are adding a `number` (`0.75`) with a `length` (`(0.3 - 0.75) * ((100vw - 320px) / (780 - 320))`)

> At + or -, check that both sides have the same type, or that one side is a `<number>` and the other is an `<integer>`. If both sides are the same type, resolve to that type. If one side is a `<number>` and the other is an `<integer>`, resolve to .<sup>[ref](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-3/#calc-notation)</sup>

The second issue, is that scale only take a number so you need to correct the formula to transform the second part into a number by removing any kind of unit (`vw`,`px`,etc).

Basically, what you want to do cannot be done this way because you have no way to convert your `(100vw - 320px)` to a number unless you consider using some JS as this is beyond CSS. Even with JS you will need to define what is the logic behind transforming a pixel number to non-pixel number.

---

Using the same formula within `right` and with `percentage` will work fine because:

> If percentages are accepted in the context in which the expression is placed, and they are defined to be relative to another type besides `<number>`, a `<percentage-token>` is treated as that type. For example, in the width property, percentages have the `<length>` type. A percentage only has the `<percentage>` type if in that context `<percentage>` values are not used-value compatible with any other type. If percentages are not normally allowed in place of the calc(), then a calc() expression containing percentages is invalid in that context.<sup>[ref](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-3/#calc-notation)</sup>

So in this case percentage is allowed to be used with `right` because we can resolve it thus the forumla will be valid because at the end it will be something like `A% + Bpx`.